# Login Multiuser with Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee

my friend and I are creating a webapp using Java EE (knowing that it's our first experience with Java EE) we do have different users to our webapp and so we would like to set the login in a way that the home page to which the user log in depend on his role but we're really stack here. Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have issue with database design.

**user :**

```
id (PK)
user_name
password
user_type_id(FK)
....
```

**user_type :**

```
id(PK)
role
```

So, with the help of this kind of design, you have common login page for every user and depend on the `user_type` you can redirect it to dashboard as per his role.

Comment: Where does he say that he plans to use a database for a user registry?

Comment: Halouane put very low information in question, so based on my guess I am just suggesting how he can differentiate `user` based on `user_type`.